# change color of a button in parent form, from a child form

Tags: c#, winforms

I need a little of advice
I have two Forms (Form1 and Form2). Form1 has a button that opens Form2, and Form2 has a button that closes Form2. Now, when I click button from Form1, its color changes. I want, after I close Form2, the button from Form1 to change to its default color. I tried this method, but it does not work..

```cs
private void btn_exit_menu_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form1 form = Application.OpenForms.OfType<Form1>().FirstOrDefault();
    form.btn_clienti.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(41, 39, 40);
    form.btn_alimente.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(41, 39, 40);
    form.btn_retete.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(41, 39, 40);
    form.btn_meniuri.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(41, 39, 40);

    Application.DoEvents();

    this.Close();
}
```

Comment: This looks like a Windows Forms question. If you ask another one, you should tag it with the win forms tag

Comment: Is Form2 being displayed with `Show()` or `ShowDialog()`?

Comment: @Idle_Mind, Form2 is a child form, it is displayed within a label in Form1. I fixed the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `onclosed` event handler when you create `form2`... and change button color. Remember to declare button public.

[From Form.OnClosed Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.onclosed?view=netcore-3.1)

**UPDATE**

I've noticed `OnClosed` is obsolete! Just use `OnFormClosed` instead.

[From Form.OnFormClosed Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.onformclosed?view=netcore-3.1)